# Detect which block method (_prepareSpecificInformation) is in use

Tags: adminhtml, email-templates, payment-methods

I have created a payment method and it has a `_prepareSpecificInformation()` that is extended under the `Mage_Payment_Block_Info`.  Just need to detect where this is being called from with in the function as there are some points that I want to show everything and others, like an email, that I don't.  This is what I have now.

```
protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null){
    $helper             = Mage::helper('centralprocessing');
    if ($this->_paymentSpecificInformation !== null) {
        return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
    }

    $info = $this->getInfo();

    $transport = new Varien_Object();
    $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);

    $transData=array();

    $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Card Type')]=$helper->getCardType($info->getCardType());
    $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Masked CC Number')]='############'.$info->getMaskedCcNumber();

    $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Response Return Code')]="".$info->getResponseReturnCode();
    $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('GUID')]=$info->getResponseGuid();
    $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Approval Code')]=$info->getApprovalCode();

    $transport->addData($transData);

    return $transport;
}
```

So I wanted to add conditions on what is added to the `$transData` array depending if it's the admin or if it's in the email and such.

***UPDATE***
The reason is that I need to put a link in with the data in the admin page only.  Also turns out that

```
$transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('GUID')]="<h1>HELLO</h1>";
```

Prints `<h1>HELLO</h1>` so the html is escaped first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Detecting when being rendered on admin pages

Here's an easy way to determine whether the block is rendered within the admin page:

```
$isAdminBlock = $this->getParentBlock() && $this->getParentBlock() instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment;
```

This works because [the admin page will assign the payment block to be a child of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php#L51).  (PDFs and emails do not contain that parent block).

You can use this approach to modify your code like so:

```
protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null) {
    $helper = Mage::helper('centralprocessing');
    if ($this->_paymentSpecificInformation !== null) {
        return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
    }

    $info = $this->getInfo();

    // Here's where the detection occurs
    $isAdminBlock = $this->getParentBlock() && $this->getParentBlock() instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment;

    $transData = array();

    $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Card Type')] = $helper->getCardType($info->getCardType());
    $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Masked CC Number')] = '############'.$info->getMaskedCcNumber();

    // Here's an example of only showing certain info to admins
    if ($isAdminBlock) {
        $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Response Return Code')]="".$info->getResponseReturnCode();
        $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('GUID')]=$info->getResponseGuid();
        $transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Approval Code')]=$info->getApprovalCode();
    }

    $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
    $transport->addData($transData);

    return $transport;
}
```

---

### Detecting between PDFs and emails

*I know this doesn't answer your specific question, but hopefully it'll help someone else with a similar issue.*

It's also possible to detect whether the block is being added to a PDF.  When this happens, Magento calls `->toPdf()` before rendering the template, so you'd just override that method, set a flag, and check the flag later:

```
public function toPdf() {
    $this->setIsPdf(true);
    return parent::toPdf();
}

protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null) {
    ...

    if ($this->getIsPdf()) {
        $transData['whatever'] = 'This will only appear in PDFs (not emails)';
    }

    // You could even combine this with the admin block check:
    if (!$isAdminBlock && !$this->getIsPdf()) {
        // We're probably being rendered inside of an email
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: wonderful, this makes perfect sense.  I have one last part on this, that the orginal intent was to add html to `$transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('GUID')]=$info->getResponseGuid();` .. but if I go `$transData[Mage::helper('payment')->__('GUID')]=$info->getResponseGuid().'<h1>HELLO</h1>';` (if the `getResponseGuid()` out put `foo` as a string) I end up with the out put of `foo<h1>HELLO</h1>` as an escaped string, not html, so I literally see that on the screen.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The HTML is being escaped by the call to [`getValueAsArray()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info.php#L115) within [the template](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml#L39).  Changing the second parameter from `true` to `false` will prevent the escaping.

Comment: An alternate approach could be modifying the template's foreach loop to check the `$_label` for your `GUID` key.  If found, manually render the value, otherwise use the existing call to `getValueAsArray()`.  Hope that helps!

Comment: oh yes yes, should have recalled that. Thank you for the clear answer, I'll get to implementation and mark this as the solution when done.

Answer (score 1):

The admin template that calls this function is `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml` but there is also a pdf that shows the payment information also, `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/pdf/default.phtml`

A good way of finding the block you have is to turn on template hints and this will show you templates and blocks used on a page.

Looking at what you need to do with your requirements I would suggest one of the following.

1. Rewrite the block `Mage_Payment_Block_Info` and check in the function if you are in the admin section via `Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()` and then making your change,
2. Listen to the event `adminhtml_block_html_before`, check for your block type and then perform the change to the html that you require.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure how to apply this information to append a link only in the admin html, are you meaning that there is a global way to say I'm in this block?

Comment: Yes, there is a number of tools, like "template hints" (inbuilt in some Mage versions this one), that provide you with info about the block/template generating a certain <markup> in your stores/ adminhtml.

Answer (score -1):

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Cc.php -> line 95
/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Payment/Info.php -> line 53
/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info.php -> line 105
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Payment/Info/Billing/Agreement.php -> line 49
/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Ccsave.php -> line 43
```

get this easy : http://doc-magento.com/ . just search your variable,function,calss from the right corner "search"